# When a link uses jQuery to do an animation prevent button being clickable again until finished

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I have a button at the side of a page that enables a user to go to the next slide (page).

Because the page size can be different widths this is calculated at the beginning.

So what the link does is run an animation. If I double click the button though it animates too far.

Here is the code I have:

```
jQuery(".nextSlide").click(function() {

slide("forward", pageSize);
    //for now assume pageSize is 950

});
```

---

```
function slide(data, pageSize) {
 var newLeft = calcLeft(data, pageSize);
 jQuery('#pageHolder').animate({
    left: newLeft
 }, 400, function() {
    calcNav(pageSize);
    calcPage(pageSize);
 });

}
```

---

```
function calcLeft(action, pageSize){
    // there will only ever be 4 slides. 0 is pos1)
var currentPos = currentPosition();
if (action == "back") {
    if (currentPos == "0") {
        left = -pageSize * 3;
    } else {    
        left = currentPos + pageSize ;  
    }

} else if (action == "forward") {

    if (currentPos == -pageSize * 3) {

        left = 0;
    } else {
        left = currentPos - pageSize ;  
    }
return left;    
}
```

---

```
function currentPosition() {
    var currentPosition = parseInt(jQuery("#pageHolder").css("left"), 10);
    return currentPosition;
}
```

So if the user clicks the button:

```
<a href="#" class="nextSlide">next</a>
```

twice this can mess up the animation.

Is there any way of making sure that either

a) when the button is pressed it cant be pressed again until the animation has completed?

or

b) slides to the next slide and then runs the animation again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your click event to a function so you can control click handling yourself. That function should do as follows:

```
function clickHandler(event) {

    // If event isn't already marked as handled, handle it
    if(event.handled !== true) {

        // Kill event handler, preventing any more clicks
        $(".nextslide").die("click");

        // Do your stuff here
        slide("forward", pageSize);

        // Mark event as handled
        event.handled = true;
    }
    // Else
    return false;
}

// Bind click to handler for the first time
$('.nextslide').live("click", clickHandler);
```

This will kill the event on the element if it's already been clicked.

Then at the end of your animation, rebind the event:

```
// Rebind refresh click handler
$('.nextSlide').live("click", clickHandler);
```

Comment: `.live ()` is depreciated. Use `.on ()`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I kind of ripped this from old code and repurposed it.

Comment: actually this isnt working.. using the code above

jQuery(".touchslider-prev").on("click", clickHandlerPrev);
                                                                           
function clickHandlerNext(event) {
    console.log (event.handled); 
} return undefined.. why?

Comment: Is it not working or are you assuming that should return false? Handled probably won't be set to anything until you set it.

Comment: i used .off and it seems to be working now. .die was removed in latest version

Comment: i will post the code here as an answer as there is still a slight problem is that is ok

Comment: Do what you will, i'm man enough to acknowledge my code was old and full of holes. :P

Comment: no.. sorry i wasnt having a go.. i appreciate the help. just unsure where to make the button clickable after the slide has finished

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery(".touchslider-prev").on("click", clickHandlerPrev);
});
```

---

```
function clickHandlerPrev(event) {

// If event isn't already marked as handled, handle it
if(event.handled !== true) {

    // Kill event handler, preventing any more clicks
    jQuery(".touchslider-prev").off("click");

    // Do your stuff here

    slide("back");

    // Mark event as handled
    event.handled = true;
} 


return false;
}
```

---

```
function slide(data) {

var newLeft = calcLeft(data, 950);

  jQuery('#pageHolder').animate({
    left: newLeft
  }, 400, function() {
    calcNav(950);
    calcPage(950);
    jQuery(".touchslider-prev").on("click", clickHandlerPrev);


  });

}
```

---

Comment: You need to rebind the event once your slide function is complete.